# Convert List to Tibble Plus Add Column With List Names

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, tibble

I'm working on a web scraping / mapping project where I've scraped address data from a restaurant website and I've stored the results as a list - in this example, called `loc_list`.

Question is, how best to convert these list items into a single data.frame / tibble (currently using `bind_rows( )`) but ALSO, in the new data.frame, have a column titled `metro` which corresponds to each list item name.  In my example, the output would have 3 `alpharetta`s, followed by 3 `atlanta`, then 1 `buford`.

```
loc_list

$alpharetta
# A tibble: 3 x 2
                  names                                                  address
                  <chr>                                                    <chr>
1 East Roswell          US 2630 Holcomb Bridge Rd Alpharetta, GA  30022
2 Old Milton US 4305 Old Milton Parkway Ste 101 Alpharetta, GA  30022
3 Windward       US 875 N Main Street Ste 306 Alpharetta, GA  30009

$atlanta
# A tibble: 3 x 2
                        names                                         address
                        <chr>                                           <chr>
1 Philips Arena        US 100 Techwood Drive Atlanta, GA  30303
2 Virginia Highlands       US 1006 N Highland Ave Atlanta, GA  30306
3 Perimeter     US 1211 Ashford Crossing Atlanta, GA  30346

$buford
# A tibble: 1 x 2
            names                                          address
            <chr>                                            <chr>
1 Woodward US 3250 Woodward Crossing Blvd Buford, GA  30519
```

Targeted output:

```
names          address       metro
East Ros...    US 2630...    alpharetta
```

Comment: `bind_rows(loc_list, .id = "metro")` You can also use `purrr::map_df` with a `.id` parameter, if you're applying a function to get to this state.

Comment: FWIW you're _actually told_ to use `dput()` to share data in questions _in the actual R tag top text_. #nojoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alistaire pointed out `bind_rows` is enough with `.id`. Here is example data:

```
alpharetta <- tibble(names=c("East Roswell", "Old Milton"),
                     address = c("US 2630 Holcomb Bridge Rd Alpharetta, GA  30022", "4305 Old Milton Parkway Ste 101 Alpharetta, GA  30022"))
atlanta <- tibble(names=c("Philips Arena", "Virginia Highlands"),
                  address = c("US 100 Techwood Drive Atlanta, GA  30303", "US 1006 N Highland Ave Atlanta, GA  30306"))

loc_list <- list(alpharetta = alpharetta, atlanta = atlanta)

bind_rows(loc_list, .id="metro")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
       metro              names                                               address
       <chr>              <chr>                                                 <chr>
1 alpharetta       East Roswell       US 2630 Holcomb Bridge Rd Alpharetta, GA  30022
2 alpharetta         Old Milton 4305 Old Milton Parkway Ste 101 Alpharetta, GA  30022
3    atlanta      Philips Arena              US 100 Techwood Drive Atlanta, GA  30303
4    atlanta Virginia Highlands             US 1006 N Highland Ave Atlanta, GA  30306
```